# Using class methods ... fails with the old "__init__() takes exactly x arguments (x+1 given)"

Tags: python, class, self, class-method

Here's some code I wrote with the purpose in mind of having more than one way to initialize my GameObject class:

```
class GameObject(object):

    def __init__(self, name, location, description, aliases=[]):
        self.name = name
        self.location = location
        self.description = description
        self.aliases = aliases
        ...

    @classmethod
    def from_values(cls, name, location, description, aliases=[]):
        return cls(name, location, description, aliases)

    @classmethod
    def from_super(cls, object):
        return cls(object.name, object.location, \
            object.description, object.aliases)
```

Specifically, the way I'm trying to use this is to call my `from_super()` method from the children classes of GameObject and return an instance of that child class, GIVEN a GameObject instance. This looks like:

```
item = o.GameObject(name, room.id, description, aliases)
if item_type == 'fix':
    item = fix.Fixture.from_super(item)
if item_type == 'move':
item = move.Moveable.from_super(item)
if item_type == 'take':
    item = take.Takeable.from_super(item)

# do something with item
```

And in Takeable:

```
import object

class Takeable(object.GameObject):

    def __init__(self, name, current_room, description):
        object.GameObject.__init__(self, name, current_room, description)
        ...
```

I thought this rather nifty, but unfortunately when I execute that last bit, it fails inside the code for GameObject, and with a very familiar error...

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "create_map.py", line 207, in 
>      `create_map()`
>    File "create_map.py", line 191, in create_map
>      `create_items(room)`
>    File "create_map.py", line 83, in create_items
>      `item = take.Takeable.from_super(item)`
>    File "/home/brian/Code/chimai/chimai/objects/object.py", line 21, in from_super
>      `return cls(object.name, object.location, object.description, object.aliases)`
>    TypeError: `__init__()` takes exactly 4 arguments (5 given)

... which I don't understand. Typically when I get this error, I forgot to include self. However, I did not forget in this case, as you can see. So I'm thinking the error has to do with something going on behind the scenes with my class method, and I was just starting to try to research exactly what that magic is, but I thought I might have one of you kind people help me to understand instead.

Thanks in advance, and sorry if I missed something obvious.

Comment: Could you post the whole/more of the traceback so it's easier to follow the flow?

Comment: Be careful with mutable default arguments: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument

Comment: Posted the traceback.

Comment: Do you have `__init__` in `Takeable`?

Comment: @Blender: I have visited that thread recently, lol. And I half-expect to run into some problems from carelessly passing around mutable/non-mutable objects soon. But is this related to the error?

Comment: Ohhhhhh. Thank you @gatto, I think I understand. `Takeable` doesn't have the `aliases` param.

Comment: Well, there you go ;) As for mutable default arguments, it's not related.

Comment: If someone posted an answer, I'd accept, lol.

Comment: Just a quick tip, it's probably best not to ever have a python file called "object.py". You're going to get very confused when you start trying to define classes that inherit from `object` in modules where you've done `import object`.

Comment: In object.py, I in fact already have code that goes like this:

    class GameObject(object):
        ...

Yeah, I guess that is bad. Advice well-taken.

Comment: Inside object.py that works, because there `object` is the normal `object` from Python. In any module where you've done `import object`, that name will now refer to the module, so if you tried `class SomeClass(object)` you'll get weird errors because you're trying to create a class that inherits from a module. And then you'll look at your class statement and everything will look fine, and then you'll try typing it into a Python interpreter and it will work, and it'll take you ages to figure out where the problem really is. Save yourself while you still can!